# In Jquery, how do I apply a class to every third (or fourth) instance of an element with a particular class?

Tags: jquery

This is what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfwPT/

i.e. make every first, sixth, eleventh, etc element with class "Noted" green, 
and make every second, seventh, twelfth, etc. element with class "Noted" blue,
and so on.

I've been trying to use eq() but I think I'm doing something wrong:

`$('span.Noted').eq(n/5).addClass('Note'n)`

which to me means, take the number the item has (whether it's #5 or #100 in the series) and divide it by five, and then use that number to assign it a class. Then in CSS I have Note1 {color:green} etc.

There must be an easier way of doing this, right?

Comment: I linked some code the last time you asked a question. The same code will work for this, you just need to have a modulus for the array index. I've edited my answer to that question to include it. While you're at it, perhaps you should accept one of the answers to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
$(function(){
    $('p:nth-child(5n+1) span.Noted').addClass('Note1');

    $('p:nth-child(5n+2) span.Noted').addClass('Note2');

    $('p:nth-child(5n+3) span.Noted').addClass('Note3');

    $('p:nth-child(5n+4) span.Noted').addClass('Note4');

    $('p:nth-child(5n) span.Noted').addClass('Note5');
});
```

Working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZfwPT/7/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// how much span should be grouped to one class
var blocksize = 5;

$('span.Noted').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("Note" + Math.ceil((i + 1) / blocksize));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
$('span.Noted').each(function(i){
 $(this).attr("id", "Note"+(i+1));
});
```

As you can see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZfwPT/6/

Comment: this will color **every** single span not a group of five elements

Comment: It will add an id to every single span, I amended what was in js fiddle where I should have looked at the question closer.